# Languages which support one-to-many relations natively?

Tags: one-to-many

Are there any computer languages which have seamless support for one-to-many relations from both ends?

i.e. I'm looking for a language where it is possible to do:

```
container.contents // set of many items
item.container     // the single container
```

By `seamless` I mean that adding an item to the contents of a container should change it's container, and changing an item's container should remove it from the old container's contents and add it to the new container's contents.

e.g.

```
item0.container = containerA
item0.container       // containerA
containerA.contents   // [item0]
containerB.contents   // []

containerB.contents.push(item0)
item0.container       // containerB
containerA.contents   // []
containerB.contents   // [item0]
```

Django supports something along these lines, though a little verbose.  I am looking for an in-memory/in-process solution, not a database.

If no languages support many-to-one relations natively, which have good support for giving such a library a native-like API?